# Is it possible to move python installation from one windows account to another?

Tags: python, installation

In a Windows Server machine, python is installed in one account in the following path:
***C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36***

I would like to move the python installation from that account to another account in the C:/ drive. Since most of the modules are already installed in that Python, I do not like to do a fresh install in the new account.

I copied the entire installation to the new location and I tried setting the following path in the new account.
***C:\Python\Python36***

But ***python --version*** did not work (even after restarting the system).

What do you think I must be doing wrong here?

Comment: Just do a fresh install. It is much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Find Python Setup, then uninstall the python.
Reinstall it again, but before the installation do it like this: choose 'Customize Installation' -> Next -> browse -> choose choose your folder, or just tick 'Install for all users' box.